# Можно ли вскарабкаться на ноги самому себе?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синонимы

Читая переводную литературу, какие только выражения не найдешь?! На глаза попались следующие действия ГГ: Герой "понял, что ему необходимо сесть. Но промахнувшись мимо края постели, он тяжело рухнул на пол.",.. а через некоторое время "он вскарабкался на ноги и вылетел за дверь...". Встает вопрос: можно ли вскарабкаться на свои же ноги? В словаре Ожегова КАРА́БКАТЬСЯ- подниматься, цепляясь ногами и руками (К. на гору), у Ушакова тоже КАРАБКАТЬСЯ — лезть вверх, цепляясь ногами и руками. Допустимо ли применение слова КАРАБКАТЬСЯ в вышеупомянутом контексте?

Comment: После тяжёлого падежа герой летает! Чудный перевод.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном Вами примере, если судить только по вырванному из контекста предложению, такое употребление некорректно. Вскарабкаться имеет значение:с трудом, усилием подняться на кого , что л., достигать (достичь) верха чего л., двигаясь снизу вверх, опираясь на что л. или цепляясь за что л. конечностями.

Однако,чтобы дать точный ответ, нужен более широкий контекст. Может, имеется в виду, что герой поднялся на чьи-либо ноги? Тогда "вскарабкаться" употреблено вполне корректно.

Comment: Герой больше ничего существенного не делал, только думал в промежутке между действием (и был в помещении один, сидя спиной к постели).

Comment: Тогда, конечно, такое употребление некорректно.

Comment: В переводах ещё и не такое встретишь... "С трудом поднялся" на ноги, конечно